# What is the best way to design Language table by country?

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a `language` database table and I have come up with following fields

```
id (auto increment)
name (Name of the language)
iso_code (ISO code, example: en)
language_code (Ex: en-us for US english)
locale
```

The above table is more generic and doesn't specify different languages of a country.
Example, Malaysia has 3 languages English (en), Malay (ms) and Chinese (zh).

Is it a good practice to link country into language table?
One of the use case I could think of is that when people access site from Malaysia, I should be able to present user with available languages in Malaysia.

[[Updated]]

```
Language
----------
id      name                code    locale
-----------------------------------------------
1       English             en      
2       American English    en-US   en_US.UTF-8
3       British English     en-GB
4       Malaysia Malay      ms-MY   
5       Chinese             zh

Country
------------
id  name            iso_code_2      iso_code_3
----------------------------------------------
1   Malaysia        MY              MYS     
2   United States   US              USA     
3   China           CN              CHN     


Malaysia has three languages Malay, English and Chinese then my third table would look like this


Country_Language
----------------------------
id      language_id     country_id
-----------------------------------
1       1               1
2       4               1
3       5               1
```

If I were query languages supported in Malaysia, I would be able to get the results from the above table. However I guess `(language_id, country_id)` should be **UNIQUE**.

Comment: Do not re-invent the wheel. use an existing localization solution. anything else is going to get you in trouble, sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a good practice to link country into language table?

No it's not, because it violates normalization.

Including the countries would lead to a repetition of data. Following your example:

```
id  name       ...  country
---------------------------------
 1  English    ...  Great Britain
 2  English    ...  Malaysia
 3  English    ...  Canada
 4  Norwegian  ...  Norway
 5  Hungarian  ...  Hungary
```

('...' stands for all your other columns. Btw. the problem is still the same if you would use a country id instead of the full name).

As you see 'English' along with it's connected data shows up three times. This repetition leads to what is called update anomaly.

Instead you should create a third table (I assume there already is a country table) which holds the relation between countries and languages:

```
language_id  country_id
-----------------------
1            42
```

You should also take a closer look at the dependencies between `iso_code`, `language_code` and `name`. Not knowing what you like to store in `locale`, I just can point to the functional dependency between the other three. This also leads to redundancy.

Especially as an application is going to be build based on it you actually might be happy on a lower normal form here. Yet, you should be aware of that issue and, if convenient, break normalization intentionally.

Comment: Repeating the name of the language isn't by itself a violation of 3NF. My guess is that the relevant dependencies are language_code -> name, name -> language_code. If I'm correct in that assumption then possibly the table violates BCNF but not 3NF. I don't know about the other columns because they aren't specified here. I do agree with your recommendation to create a country table but just not quite for the reason you have given.

Comment: @sqlvogel Yeah, you are right of course - thanks a lot for that correction. Why did I think of 3NF? Also it's actually `name` not `locale`. I'll edit that immediately.

Comment: @MyBrainHurts  Thanks for the suggestions. I have updated my design based on you guys suggestions. May not be the perfect solution, its based on my current database design :-).